# Alexa not saying date

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Whenever I test my skill, it is not saying the date, even though the var is in the this.emit

Here is my code:

```
  'WelcomeAlarm': function () {
var speechOutput = "This is a test";
var todayUser = new Date();
var dd = todayUser.getDate();
var mm = todayUser.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = todayUser.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) {
dd = '0'+dd
};
if(mm<10) {
mm = '0'+mm
};
var today = mm  + dd + yyyy;

this.emit(':tellWithCard', speechOutput, today);
```

Here is my service response:

```
    "speechletResponse": {
  "outputSpeech": {
    "ssml": "<speak> This is a test </speak>"
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs), it appears that the syntax is:

```
this.emit(':tellWithCard', speechOutput, cardTitle, cardContent, imageObj);
```

Therefore, you are passing `today` as the `cardTitle`. That is why it is not being spoken.

Comment: Hi @party58965, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.